# Meaning of "I wonder" after being asked a question

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, phrase-choice

I was doing some grammar exercises on a book and this sentence confuses me.

> Do you think Philip would be good at the job?
>
> *Hmm, I wonder.*

What does the word *wonder* mean in this sentence? How can I interpret this sentence? Can I replace "*I wonder*" with "*I doubt it*"?

Comment: When creating a question, please use a title that better describes the question. The title "*How can I interpret this weird sentence?*" won't help other learners determine if this question is what they are looking for.

Comment: Sorry, I will be careful next time.

Answer (score 3):

If someone says that they "wonder" after a question is asked, it means they are wondering about the answer to the question.

> Do you think Philip would be good at the job?
>
> *Hmm, I wonder if he would be good.*

It doesn't necessarily mean that they doubt that we will be good, it just means they don't know the answer to the question but they have some interest in it.